# What was Sir Issac Newton's thoughts on the origin of the Universe?

Tags: newton, gravity

Newton founded the Law of Gravitation based on the observations of Kepler and Galilei. He later invented the mathematical framework which eventually helped him formulate his theory of gravitation. That same framework was used to predict the position of the moon and other heavenly bodies in the night sky.

Many people claim that an apple falling of a tree is what inspired him to pursue the theory of gravitation. That may even perhaps be the case, however, that may not be enough for our generation to understand it. I think it is probably the realization that all heavenly objects are falling into each other. The moon, for e.g is also falling into earth, but it doesn't reach earth surface since there is some heavenly force making it sustain an orbit around the Earth.

Along this line of reasoning it becomes apparent that Newton had these same ideas. He would have been naturally curious as to what set these heavenly bodies in motion.

I am just curious to know what was his theory of the universe at that point.

Comment: Newton was a very religious man and he never doubted the Biblical account of the creation of the Universe. Differently from today's creation theory of the Big Bang, he believed that the Universe was infinite and tried to establish whether it was stable or unstable based on his Gravitation theory. Here however, he made a mathematical mistake and concluded erroneously that it was unstable (Correspondence with Richard Bentley[1692–3].Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1924.)

Comment: "*Gravity must be caused by an agent acting constantly according to certain laws*"; "*This most elegant system of the sun, planets, and comets could not have arisen without the design and dominion of an intelligent and powerful being... and the fixed stars would, through their gravity, gradually fall on each other, were they not carried back by the counsel of the supreme Being.*" The space he called "*God's sensorium*". And so on, see [Snobelen, The Myth of the Clockwork Universe](https://isaacnewtonstheology.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/the-myth-of-the-clockwork-universe.pdf).